# Expected Value of the absolute value of the sum of random variables

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, normal-distribution

Hi everyone and thanks in advance.

Let's say we have a random variable Y which can be expressed as the sum of two other complex random variables X and W, i.e. $ Y = X + W $. $X$ and $W$ are independent. $X$ variable stands for the user signal and has the following statistics:

$$ E[X] = 0 $$
$$ Var[X] = E[(X-E[X])·(X-E[X])^*] = E[|X|^2] = P_x $$

Where $X^*$ is the conjugate transpose of X.

$W$ variable stands for a zero mean white noise with normal distribution and variance $\sigma_w^2$:

$$ W \sim \mathcal{CN} (0,\sigma_w^2)$$

$E[Y]$ and $Var[Y]$ can be easily computed, but my question is referring to $|{Y}|$. How should I compute the expected value $E[|Y|]$ ?

Comment: Assuming that $W$ is independent of $X$, $$E(|X+W|)=2\sigma_W E\left(\varphi(-X/\sigma_W)\right)+E\left(X(1-2\Phi(-X/\sigma_W))\right).$$

Comment: Hi, $X$ and $W$ are independent. Forgot to say, I am adding this info.
Thanks.
However, which functions are $\phi$ and $\Phi$ ?

Comment: Standard normal PDF and CDF.